# can't get the personal customer class to compile, something wrong with the constructor?

Tags: java, class, constructor

It's a simple program to add/remove different types of customers.

I know it's probably something simple, but has had me for a while now.

Keep getting the error,

```
constructor Customer in class Customer cannot be applied to the given types; required; java.lang. String, Address, char found:no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the customer constructor but don't know.

```
public class Address
{
    private String street,town;

    /**
     * Constructor for Address
     * 
     * @param street    The street
     * @param town      The town
     */
    public Address (String street, String town)
    {
        this.street = street;
        this.town = town;
    }

    /**
     * @return   The street
     */
    public String getStreet()
    {
        return street;
    }

    /**
     * @return   The town
     */
    public String getTown()
    {
        return town;
    }

    /**
     * Change the street part of the address
     * 
     * @param street    The new street
     */
    public void setStreet(String street)
    {
        this.street = street;
    }

    /**
     * Change the town part of the address
     * 
     * @param street    The new town
     */
    public void setTown(String town)
    {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return street + "\n" + town;
    }
}
```

```
public class Name
{
    private String fName, lName;

    /** 
     * Constructor for Name
     * 
     * @param fName     The first name
     * @param lName     The last name
     */
    public Name(String fName, String lName)
    {
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
    }  

    /** 
     * @return  The first name
     */
    public String getFName()
    {
        return fName;
    }

    /** 
     * @return  The last name
     */
    public String getLName()
    {
        return lName;
    }

    /**
     * Amend the first name
     * 
     * @param fName The new first name
     */
    public void setFName(String fName)
    {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

     /**
     * Amend the last name
     * 
     * @param lName The new last name
     */
    public void setLName(String lName)
    {
        this.lName = lName;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return fName + " " + lName;
    }

}
```

```
public class Customer
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String accountNumber;
    private Address address;
    private int balance;
    private char customerType;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Customer
     */
    public Customer(String accountNumber, Address address, char customerType)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.accountNumber= accountNumber;
        this.address= address;
        balance = 0;
        this.customerType=customerType;
    }

    /** 
     * Adds money to the ammount in the account
     */
    public void credit(int amt)
    {
        balance= balance + amt;
    }

    /**
     * removes money from the ammount in the account
     */
    public void debit(int amt)
    {
        balance= balance - amt;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the account number of the customer
     */
    public String getAccountNumber()
    {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    /**
     * returns the address of the customer
     */
    public Address getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * returns the balance of the customer
     */
    public int getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the type of customer Bussiness or Personal
     */
    public char getCustomerType()
    {
        return customerType;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address)
    {
       this.address=address;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output ="Account Number: " + accountNumber + "Customer Type: " + customerType  + "balance: " + getBalance() + "Address: " + super.toString();
        return output;
    }
}
```

```
public class PersonalCustomer extends Customer
{
    // instance variables
    private Name name;

    public PersonalCustomer(String accountNumber, Address address, Name name)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.accountNumber= accountNumber;
        this.address=address;
        this.name= Name;
    }

    public Name getName()
    {
        return + "Address: " + super.toString();
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output = getFName() + getLName() + "\n" + "Account Number: " + accountNumber + "\n" 
                                + "Customer Type: " + customerType + "\n" + "Address: " + super.toString() + "\n"  
                                            + "balance: " + getBalance();
        return output; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Put your code in the question, not in a link to some external site.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying you are calling:

```
new Customer();
```

but the customer requires a String, Address and char eg:

```
new Customer("Bob", new Address("Cool Street","Awesome Town"), 'a');
```

This seems a bit odd but the reason is that your child class implicitly calls the parent constructor if you don't.

```
public PersonalCustomer(String accountNumber, Address address, Name name)
{
    // super(); //calls the parent constructor with no arguments without you seeing
    this.accountNumber= accountNumber;
    this.address=address;
    this.name= Name;
}
```

All you need to do is change the PersonalCustomer constructor to

```
public PersonalCustomer(String accountNumber, Address address, Name name)
{
    super(accountNumber, address, 'p'); //or whatever customer type they are supposed to get
    this.name= Name;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i can't get the personalCustomer class to complile at all because it throws that error, no idea how to get rid of it

Comment: @StefanoMantini - Change how you're calling your `Customer` class. Or add a new constructor with zero arguments.

Comment: So i should change the Constructor in PersonalCustomer to:

    public PersonalCustomer(String accountNumber, Address address, Name name)
    {
        super(accountNumber, address);
        this.name = name;
    }

Comment: Almost, the customer constructor also takes in a type. I assumed it would be something like 'p' in my updated answer ^

Comment: LifeSaver, thank you so much
and to everyone who contributed

Answer (score 1):

If you don't define a constructor, there's an implicit no-args constructor.

But, when you define a constructor with arguments, the implicit no-rags constructor disappears.

You must have had some code prior to defining the new constructor that used the default constructor, ie `new Customer()`. **You must define a no-args constructor to fox your problem**

This little gem catches out many a new java programmer.

Comment: A no-rags constructor, huh?

Comment: I make sure that all of my constructors wear a top hat and monocle.

Comment: @adamdunson lol. damn iPhone autocorrect :/

Comment: @JackManey lol. You got me there (iPhone autocorrect at work)